# Why when i use global vauiable outside the controller return an object when using select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

when i try to use a global variable outside the controller it return an object
i`m using ancestry gem and i wanted to return all children in all nodes so that user can only pick a subcategory
this is my controller code

```
def new
@product = current_user.products.build
    $categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
    @main = []
   Category.all.each do |category|
    if category.parent_id.nil?
     next
      else
     @main << category
    end 
    end
   $subcat = @main.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
   end
```

This is the code for view

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label t('category'), :class => 'control-label col-lg-2-offset' %>
<div class="col-lg-10-offset">
  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select($subcat), :prompt => "Select Category") %>
</div>
<%=f.error_span(:category_id) %>
```

When i used the controller code in the categories_controller it kept returning and objects instead of return the category name

in any other loop or function it acted normal, when i used it in any other controller and it returned what i expected except when i used select_tag

so i can put it in array return it and show it but i can not use select_tag because it will return an object

so i had to put it in product controller , new action

In any other place it will return an object even though in application controller and even though it is a global variable , i should be able to use it any where.

so why select_tag did this ?

Another issue is when i use an instance variable it did not work too.

Thanks

Comment: Can we see the object?

Comment: Which object do you mean?
Category and Product objects are normal scaffold objects
nothing fancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NEVER use global variables. During my 9 years of experience in rails I faced only one single situation, when it was ok. In your case it's absolutely not ok.

What I suggest you to do:

Define `subcategories` scope in Category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :subcategories, -> { where.not(parent: nil) }
end
```

Leave only one row in your controller:

```
def new
  @product = current_user.products.build
end
```

Replace `options_for_select` in your view with `options_from_collection_for_select`:

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label t('category'), :class => 'control-label col-lg-2-offset' %>
<div class="col-lg-10-offset">
  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.subcategories, :id, :name), prompt: "Select Category") %>
</div>
<%=f.error_span(:category_id) %>
```

Comment: He is looking to add categories in the array where the parent is not nil. In your scope you would want `scope :subcategories, -> { where.not(parent: nil) }`  instead

Comment: Thanks for your reply , it really helped, however it did not answered my question, why i can not traverse on a global variable when i use this function select_tag?

Comment: Have you tried yo use debugger and check whether this global variable is defined in a context of the view?

Comment: It is defined , i can retrieve it any where except with select_tag

Comment: Can you provide more details on your issues? I get that you expect to get category name while you get category object, but where this happen? In select display values? In request params when you submit a form? Or where? It's not obvious from your question

Comment: Yup in create action, i get a list of the objects instead getting the name, in other hand in index the same function works, so i can create the product with the object it self but i can not get the name only in create / edit 
while i can manipulate it in any other place

Comment: @Amr Please, provide a `create` action code and point a place where exactly do you have an error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of ruby's inheritance chain. You can define that on some parent class of all your controllers as a constant, normally ApplicationController
for sample

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  BASE_URL = "www.url.com/something/"
end
```

Then it will become available to all is children, namely `PostsController < ApplicationController`

for pass variable from controller to view you should use instance variable(  @) or global class variable (@@)

your best choice is instance variable( @)